# Adding logic to existing 240 V AC circuit

Tags: relay

I have some heating circuitry which runs on 240 V. I need an output from an XOR gate from two points on this circuitry. I was thinking I could do the gate with relays but couldn’t find any relays with a 240v coil that weren’t large and expensive.

[image: image of circuit]

The diagram below shows a part of the heating circuitry around a zone valve and two points that can either be 240 VAC or 0 V. I want to read these points through an XOR gate.

Is it best for me to just buy these 240 V relays and use them or is there a neat way to bring down the 240 V input to a sensible logic voltage and use cheap low voltage coil relays? I’m open to alternatives to relays as a whole and don’t mind what voltage the XOR output is.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean – a heater doesn't *output* 240V? I think a small sketch of the situation would explain things. Your 240V is probably AC - you'll need to also explicitly tell us what you mean with "XOR" of AC voltages.

Comment: It is AC, its more sort of probing points that can either be at 240vac or 0v and using them in a logic circuit. I'll add a sketch ASAP

Comment: I don't there are transistors which can handle 240V , you would use thyristors for this job but the logic of a thyristor is different than a transistor.

Comment: Are you aware of transformers?

Comment: https://www.trcelectronics.com/View/Mean-Well/IRM-30-5ST.shtml?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlfGlmdH47wIVi8DICh2ggwDiEAQYAyABEgINxPD_BwE $15 usd ... is that expensive?

Comment: @MarcusMüller r u talking to me?

Comment: @MissMulan no, to James (otherwise I would have mentioned your name :) )

Comment: I am aware of transformers yes

Comment: @JamesConway that'd be a cheap way to control lower-voltage relays with 240V AC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmZVB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Mains XOR using relays.*

It seems unnecessarily complicated to change voltage levels. An XOR can be created using two relays. Mains powered relays can be obtained in small form-factor. Look for "ice-cube" relays, for example.

[image]

*Figure 2. A selection of ice-cube relays.*

Double-check the contacts are rated to suit your requirements.

Comment: This might be the best option... is there no way to reduce size/cost?

Comment: 1. Safety. 2. Reliability. 3. Ease of maintenance. Your XOR requirement makes it difficult to do electronically with mains.

Comment: @JamesConway  you haven't even defined a price range that'd be acceptable to you, but seriously: two relays with a 240VAC coil rating are [~3€](https://www.reichelt.de/print-steckrelais-c7621.html?ACTION=2&GROUPID=7621&SEARCH=%2A&START=0&OFFSET=16&nbc=1&SID=9674445b86527db546ca51144862216ecc574b49a13423a4f4daf) or [6€](https://www.reichelt.de/industrierelais-c7622.html?ACTION=2&GROUPID=7622&SEARCH=%2A&START=0&OFFSET=16&nbc=1&SID=9674445b86527db546ca51144862216ecc574b49a13423a4f4daf) each. How on earth is that "expensive" in context of heater control?

Comment: As seen in the answer below, I had found them being about $10-15.